# Buck converter: Additional circuitry working not clear

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, buck

Saw the below schematic of a buck converter, but not able to figure out the working of the marked section. It is shown Node 1 is at 16 V.

Looks like sensing the differential voltage across inductor, but adding C3 in series doesn't make it any differential filter. I am totally clueless how it can boost to 16 V. Even the internal driver power supply is only 3.3 V which would cause BOOST pin to swing between 12 and 15.3 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKGyCV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Have you tried to search for buck bootstrap capacitor and read any of the application notes which come up?

Comment: Yes, C1 is the bootstrap capacitor . Iam clear with regular bootstrap functionality where a cap ( sometimes an R in series as well) is added between switch node and bootstrap pin for driving high side switch.

Doubt is on the marked section. Is it related to bootstrap anyways?

Comment: Sorry, I can't really follow your schematic. What does the datasheet say about it? How does it function internally?

Comment: @Winny: Datasheet doesn't mention about this additional circuitry. Only bootstrap capacitor is needed for normal buck operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the dotted box is a **capacitor-diode charge-pump** that takes the high frequency square wave (12 volts p-p) on the raw output of your converter, feeds it through R1 and C3 and then clamps the lower peak of the waveform to Vout (5.6 volts) with diode D2.

This is then rectified by D3 and smoothed by C5 to produce roughly 16 volts DC at the output. It's not very accurate but it does work and, it works better when Schottky diodes are used when the supply voltages are low to moderate.

Here is an example of charge-pump that generates **negative voltages** using the same principle: -

[image]

Image taken from [this site](https://www.edn.com/capacitive-voltage-conversion-aka-the-charge-pump/).

Here's another example that generates a positive output greater than Vin: -

[image]

Image from [this site](https://blog.mbedded.ninja/electronics/components/power-regulators/charge-pumps/).

And here's how you can cascade them to produce even higher voltages: -

[image]

Image from [this site](https://circuits-diy.com/charge-pump-circuit-getting-higher-voltage-from-low-voltage-source/). And [here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_multiplier) a wiki article about them.

Comment: You've illustrated a Dickson, not a Cockcroft-Walton, the difference being the output impedance. If the caps are cascaded, it's a CW, if all the caps come from the input terminal, then it's a Dickson.

Comment: @Neil_UK according the the wiki page the photograph is a cockcroft walton multiplier. Or, maybe you are saying something else (I expect you are)? Maybe I should say it's related to the cw.... rather than it's sometimes called the cw...

Comment: The schematic 'Charge Pump Circuit' is a Dickson, all the capacitors return to the drive terminal(s), it has an output impedance linear in the number of stages, but requires capacitors rated for the output voltage. A CW has the caps cascaded, so rated for the input voltage, but output impedance goes as the square of the number of stages. Very different applications for the two circuits. The picture is of course a CW.

Comment: I've changed my word usage.

Comment: Not good enough yet.  As Dickson and CW have such different applications (Dickson low voltage low impedance, CW high voltage high impedance), you should separate the schematic and the picture, and describe each of them correctly.

Comment: To make my life easier and avoid an argument I'm going to remove any mention of it.